# How to use public property in actioninvoke in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this code

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     if (CurrentUser != null)
     {
            UserManager.User usr = (User.User)CurrentUser;
     }
}
```

I have done  `AdminController : TestController`

Now what is the way to access this currentUser in the actioninvoke which I use it for check that user is admin or not

```
 public class AdminAuthorize : ActionFilterAttribute 
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Is their anyway to use currentUser variable in this invoker.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the current controller instance from the Controller property of the filterContext.

```
public class AdminAuthorize : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);

        var currentUser = ((AdminController)filterContext.Controller).CurrentUser;

        // do what you need with currentUser
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't better you grap the current user from `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` ? So you can use this ActionFilter for all Controllers ?